# Bulk text2speech Generation with R

Tags: text-to-speech

Is it possible to loop through a list of words in R that can each be generated into separate “speech” files using the speech2text website?

https://www.text2speech.org/

To make one file manually one has to type in the text one one page then submit it. A second page then opens with the option to download the file. Since I want to do many of these I would like to find a way to automate it. I have no idea how to approach this idea though.

EDIT

So I am using "say" on mac based on a the helpful comments. I am running it through R using a loop for all strings in a vector

```
  for(i in 1:nrow(test[1:5])){

      system("say", intern =F,input = test$English[i])%>%saveRDS(paste0("/Users/Desktop/tts/", test$English[i],".aiff"))

    }
```

This creates the files as expected in the expected location but the .aiff files won't play in any media player. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a CLI based solution for TTS, like espeak/espeak-ng (cross-platform), festival (linux), say (osx) or via powershell on windows ([here's a script](https://gist.github.com/lselden/cde51ca2debdd7c7c16ea4abf621f8d5)). Looks like the page you're referencing is using [flite](http://www.festvox.org/flite/), which is a lightweight *(and downloadable)* version of festival.